# Sending automated mail from a shared mail Google Mail box

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

I have a work shared Gmail box and would like to automate a process where I can send out a number of e-mails.  I can send automated e-mails from my work personal Gmail address using the following:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 1;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 4)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var body_message = row[1];       // Second column
    var subject = row[2];
    var name = row[3];
    //SLE adding attachment variable
    var attachment = row[4]
    //var message = "Dear " + row[3] + ",\n\n" + row[1]; // Assemble the body text
    var message ="Dear "+name+",\n\n"+body_message
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);

  }
}
```

But if there a way I can send the mail so it looks like its come from a shared box?

So instead of the mail hitting someone's mail box from `StaceyC@company.com` the mail would be from `SharedAddress@company.com`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to send emails from a shared google mailbox with the `MailApp.sendEmail() method`, but it is possible with `GmailApp.sendEmail()`.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)

To do so, you can specify the Advanced parameter “`from`”, which allows you to send the email from any of your aliases, which you can retrieve with `GmailApp.getAliases()`.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getAliases()
So, provided that your shared g-mail box is one of your aliases, you can send the e-mail in this way:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {from: 'your_alias'})
```

To add your Gmail Collaborative Inbox as an alias, you have to adjust your Google Groups Settings:

Go to Manage `Group->Permissions->Posting permissions->Post`
 and allow (temporarily) anyone on the web to post to the group.

This is necessary to receive the verification message for adding your group inbox as an alias to the user account(s) from which you want to send emails on behalf of the group.

To add the group inbox as an alias, go in Gmail to `Settings->Accounts->Send mail as->Add another email address`. Add the email address of the group, you will receive a verification code in the group inbox. After this procedure you can send emails with GmailApp as explained above.