send mail from delegated account on trigger
I have a script that sends an email when a checkbox is ticked in a google sheet.
I need to setup a trigger so that this happens on edit. - Works fine when setup from my own google workspace account.
However I need the email to send on trigger from another google workspace account that I only have deletegate mail access to.
Is that possible to setup? and if so, how?
I've looked into this and am super confused. Any clarification would be helpful. - Do I need full access to said email account instead?

You can use GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {from: 'your_alias'}) to send mail from another account you own. (make sure it's set up in your aliased emails, add that in your gmail settings)
There is also a github library out there that you can use: https://github.com/coreyjansen/Google-App-Script-Send-Email-Service-Account
Sources:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SkgBhPSNDpI
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56888391/24976999
https://support.google.com/docs/thread/180955837/script-send-email-from-different-address?hl=en

how does this work if someone else actions the trigger on edit? Will it continue to work even if they don't have delegate access on their google account?

If you setup the trigger on your account, it should work regardless of who activates it. This is because the trigger is set to fire on any edit, not just your edit. @ralphie_palphie

you should not leave links that might expire as answers.
Always provide additional supporting informations even if it's a copy paste of these websites
